# Faster rendering by using blitting is not working in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graph, rendering

Hello fellow developers,

I am working on a project where I have to plot real time data coming from the sensors. I have created a naive generator that gives data points to plot. I was referencing the code from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html) but it doesn't draw anything, even though the program is reading all the data points from the file. I have include screenshots of the outputs.

[The first value in the tuple is the x value and the second value is the list of y value. I am plotting only the 1 value from the y value's list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgfar.jpg)

[The graph opens but the plot is not drawn.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbXNc.png)

What could be the possible issue with the code?

```
from getData import GetData

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
# matplotlib.use('MacOSX')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def getNextPoint(getDataObj):

    dataPoint = getDataObj.__next__()
    if dataPoint != None:
        x,y = dataPoint
        print(x,y)
        return x,y
    else:
        return getNextPoint(getDataObj)


def run(niter=1000):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    getDataObj = GetData()
    x, y = getNextPoint(getDataObj)

    points = ax.plot(x, y[0], animated=True)[0]

    plt.show(block=False)

    plt.pause(0.1)
    
    background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)

    ax.draw_artist(points)

    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)



    for ii in range(niter):

        # restore background
        fig.canvas.restore_region(background)

        # update the xy data
        x, y = getNextPoint(getDataObj)
        points.set_data(x, y[0])

        # redraw just the points
        ax.draw_artist(points)

        # fill in the axes rectangle
        fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
        fig.canvas.flush_events()

        ax.autoscale()
        # plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Just recommending that matplolib is not the best for real-time data visulazation.

Comment: you could add `GetData()` with some code which generate data - so we could copy and run it.

Comment: @furas GetData() function reads the data from the sensor generated CSV file. Sharing the code of GetData() won't be of much help here. You can use any value of x and y generated in real time to run the program.

Comment: you could add `GetData()` with random values. People rather will skip question instead of creating `GetData()` to run code. Other problem is: I created some GetData but it can't work with your code because you use `y[0]` and I don't understand why you use `[0]`. It seems your `GetData` gives something different than I expected.

Comment: @RitikAgarwal always add a minimum reproducible example with all the necessary input data, constants, functions. I second furas, please do not assume people will create input data to solve your problem.